# Android create iphone-like Gradient

Tags: android, gradient

I need to create black iphone like gradient in my android application. Please view black gradient at the top in the image below. How to do it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Sure you want such an ugly gradient?

Comment: do I have better option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#FF000000"
      android:endColor="#FF8E8E8E"
      android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: but this gradient is not glossy. How to apply this effect?

Comment: It works, however I hadt to switch the start and the end colors

Answer (score 6):

I've posted a blog about an Iphone look an Android:

http://www.dibbus.com/2011/06/android-gradient-toolbar/

You can find some examples of gradients and what is possible using xml and/or 9-pacth images.

Comment: That's quality man, but I think you forgot to include the bar_blue.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

You can create gradients in XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="400"
                  android:startColor="#88cce7" android:endColor="#075e81"/>

       </shape>
```

This example is a round gradient but by changing type param you can create others.
Include this code in a xml file in your drawable folder and you can refer to that file when you set a background. ie. android:background="your drawable file"

Comment: which params needs to change?

Comment: Change the android:type param to get different kinds of gradients. You can find much more info about gradients and params from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was messing around to get this same effect for a customer who wants a copy of his iPad app on Android, this is what I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#FF333333"
        android:centerY="2%"
        android:endColor="#FF000000"
        android:startColor="#FF8E8E8E" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```