# How to display gradient effect from top to bottom in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell How to dispaly gradient effect from top to bottom  in android .can anybody provide example

Thanks

Comment: This has been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510585/android-create-iphone-like-gradient

Answer (score 64, accepted):

make an xml file in your dawable folder name it like `gradient_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#000" 
        android:endColor="#fff"
        android:angle="90"
     />
</shape>
```

and set it as background to your `View`.

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
```

or

```
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
```

Comment: I want to specify height of start color can you tell how to do?

Comment: it is not possible, however you can specify `android:centerColor="#fff"` also, and you can also define colours array programmatically, in which you can have more than three colours. for example [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6116273/593709).

Answer (score 8):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient

        android:angle="90"
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#000000" />

</shape>
```

here if you set the angle to the `270` the start color will appear at the bottom and the end color at the top 
if you set the angle to `90` it will be reversed

Answer (score 1):

You can used a custom view to do that. With this solution, it's finished the gradient shapes of all colors in your projects:

```
class GradientView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

    // Properties
    private val paint: Paint = Paint()
    private val rect = Rect()

    //region Attributes
    var start: Int = Color.WHITE
    var end: Int = Color.WHITE
    //endregion

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        // Update Size
        val usableWidth = width - (paddingLeft + paddingRight)
        val usableHeight = height - (paddingTop + paddingBottom)
        rect.right = usableWidth
        rect.bottom = usableHeight
        // Update Color
        paint.shader = LinearGradient(0f, height.toFloat(), 0f, 0f,
                start, end, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
        // ReDraw
        invalidate()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint)
    }

}
```

I also create an open source project **[GradientView](https://github.com/lopspower/GradientView)** with this custom view:

https://github.com/lopspower/GradientView

```
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:gradientview:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

To display gradient effect from top to bottom in android with transparent:

1. Create a new XML file in res/drawable folder with the name gradient_transparent.xml and add following code.

.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#90000000"
            android:endColor="#00ffffff"
            android:angle="90"
            />
    </shape>
```

In XML Layout file

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_middle">
</LinearLayout>
```